# Validating Azure AD JWT in C#

Tags: azure-active-directory

Validate the azure AD jwt from your C# code by extracting the appid/clientid from the token. The below mentioned code will take token as string and validate your client id with the clientid/appid extracted from the token

```
public bool Validate(string token)
    {
        string clientId = "Your appid/clientid";
        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";                      
        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = config.SigningKeys.FirstOrDefault(),
            ValidateLifetime = false
        };

        System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        SecurityToken jwt;

        var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);
        ClaimsPrincipal claims = result;

        var claimValue = claims.Claims.GetEnumerator();
        string appId = "";
        if (claimValue != null)
        {
            while (claimValue.MoveNext())
            {
                if (claimValue.Current.Type == "appid")
                {
                    appId = claimValue.Current.Value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (appId == clientId)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }      

    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: In case you want to validate the tokens manually in your code, here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation) and this [blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/03/03/principles-of-token-validation/) for your reference.  It is recommended not to set the ValidateIssuer to false.