# Validating an Azure AD generated JWT signature and algorithm in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt

I am new to Azure AD. We are using v1.0 token. I have an Azure JWT token validation routine mostly based on [ValidateSignature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168097/validating-azure-ad-jwt-in-c-sharp) and [AzureTokenValidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554056/azure-ad-why-cant-i-validate-jwt-token-issued-by-azure-ad-for-my-web-api-get)
The below is my ClaimsTransformer:

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
<do something>
var token = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
if (Validate(token))
{ 
             <proceed to add claims>
}
```

and my validation routine:

```
 public bool Validate(string token)
        {
            string stsEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
            TokenValidationParameters parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net/<mytenant-id>",
                ValidAudience = <my client-id>,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken jwt;
            bool verified;
            try
            {
               var handler = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);
               var signature = ((System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken)jwt).RawSignature;
                string algorithm = ((System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken)jwt).Header["alg"].ToString();
                if (signature.Length == 0 || algorithm.ToLower().Equals("none"))
                {
                    tokenVerified = false;
                }
                tokenVerified = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                tokenVerified = false;
            }
            return tokenVerified;
        }
```

Please tell me if I am doing the right thing or can I just use (in my Validate(string token)

```
try
{
   var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out _);
   verified = true;
}
catch {
   verified = false;
}
```

and is, the checking for algorithm (to not accept "none" in alg) and signature presence is required or this way to check is right? There is no "secret keys"

Comment: Any reason you are not implementing standard Azure AD JWT authentication in your app? Why write manual validation?

Comment: hi junas no reason, since I am new I don't know if any exists. Are there any routines? Or am I missing something obvious (Mostly I may not know). Are you able to help?

Comment: Here's the official sample on building an API protected by Azure AD JWTs: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/README.md

Answer (score 0):

JwtBearer middleware, like the OpenID Connect middleware in web apps, validates the token based on the value of `TokenValidationParameters`. The token is decrypted as needed, the claims are extracted, and the signature is verified. The middleware then validates the token by checking for this data:

```
    Audience: The token is targeted for the web API.
    Sub: It was issued for an app that's allowed to call the web API.
    Issuer: It was issued by a trusted security token service (STS).
    Expiry: Its lifetime is in range.
    Signature: It wasn't tampered with.
```

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration)

**Example:**

```
           String token = "Token";  
            string myTenant = "Tenant Name";  
            var myAudience = "Audience";  
            var myIssuer = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0", myTenant);  
            var mySecret = "Secrete";  
            var mySecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySecret));              
            var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", myTenant);  
            var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());  
            var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();  
  
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();  
  
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters  
            {  
                ValidAudience = myAudience,  
                ValidIssuer = myIssuer,  
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,  
                ValidateLifetime = false,  
                IssuerSigningKey = mySecurityKey  
            };  
  
            var validatedToken = (SecurityToken)new JwtSecurityToken();  
  
            // Throws an Exception as the token is invalid (expired, invalid-formatted, etc.)  
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);  
            Console.WriteLine(validatedToken);  
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @ShrustiJoshi-MT. But as you can see in my code I don't have a "mySecurityKey". There is no secret shared between Azure and local API. Is this secret a must to validate the signature? Is there a way to validate the token's signature without this key?